# How do I pop() elements inside the list in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I just want to ask if how should I pop certain elements inside the list.

Let's say I have this list:

`c = ['123','456','789']`

When I type this:

`print c[0][0]`

It prints a value `'1'`,

And somehow I want to delete the first element of the first value.

So that the output will be:

`c = ['23','456','789']`

But I have a problem in using `pop()`.

I tried this but no luck:

`c.pop(0, 0) # takes only one argument`

Or

`c[0].pop(0) # string doesn't have an attribute pop`

Is there a way to solve my dilemma?

If this problem has a duplicate, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable. As such, they can't be modified once created.

If all you want to do is "remove" the first character of the first string in the list `c` you can use slicing (that returns a new string):

`c[0] = c[0][1:]`

Read more on slicing here: [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)